# Cant make Angular 1.5 (in typescript) component work

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I can't make this code work, don't see why it's not showing the button :(

Any ideas? Thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/slishnevsky/Let38jho/10/

**Angular/Typescript**

```
let app = angular.module('app', []);

export class MyController {

    public name: string;

    constructor() {}

}

export class MyComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {

    public bindings: any;
    public controller: any;
    public controllerAs: string;
    public template: string;

    constructor() {
        this.bindings = {
            name: '@'
        };
        this.controller = MyController;
        this.controllerAs = 'vm';
        this.template = '<button>{{vm.name}}</button>';
    }
}

app.component('MyComponent', new MyComponent());
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app='app'>

    <my-component name='Miranda'></my-component>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/13ju990x/

two issues:

1. Typescript transpiles the `export` keyword to amd or commonjs (or umd) format. 
   [Look here for a quick example.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%7D) And we don't have any module loader working in jsfiddle (I assume jsfiddle simpley takes your code and puts it in a `<script>` tag). You can simply open developer tools and see `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined` in your original code.
2. Angular uses Kebab-case. so you need to write `app.component('myComponent', new MyComponent());` and not `'MyComponenet'`. It's stupid, I know.